# Magento file Uploading in latest version

Tags: magento, import-from-excel

i used to work on  **Magento ver. 1.7.0.1**. i have found **media/import** folder for uploading bulk data, but now i installed latest **Magento ver 1.7.0.2**. in this version i did'nt find **import** folder in media.

is this folder moved to any other location in latest version.

here is the screen shot for my earlier version of Magneto.

[image]

current version of magento.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No the folder have to be in the same location. Just create this dir again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to create a folder with name "custom_options". Try this i think it will solve your prob.