# Dint find image upload option in newly installed Magento version

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have installed new version of **Magento 1.7.0.2** in my localhost(**XAMPP**).

I am trying to **upload** images related to products. But i dint find the **upload** and **Browse** Buttons.

Is this a problem due to improper installation ? If yes i tried installing the same on another machine. But same result.

Here is the screen shot.
[image]

How to fix this ?

Comment: Try Installing latest version of flash player in your browser.

Comment: @RohitS : can u help me for below question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936085/magento-file-uploading-in-latest-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install latest version of flash player in your browser.