# Magento admin panel product images not able to see or upload images

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

"TypeError: Flex.Uploader is not a constructor"
 in the admin panel (catalog/manager product) i am having this error upload button gone in product image tab. the above mentioned is one of the 
(errors showing up in a console using firebug). nothing was done code wise it just started to appear and we tried to update the files from latest version of magento or the parallel (with backup).

Comment: I voted to close; as this question is confusing.  First, off, writing in all caps is considered yelling on the Internet, please do not do that in your subject line.  Second, what is the admin panel? Third, what is the code that gives you this error? Are you providing us the full error?  Fourth, what is the product image tab?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/q/14999385/1957705. This might help you.